How can i select one of declared structure and make alias?
enum class Color { RED, BLACK };
enum class TreeModel { AVL, RED_BACK, SPLAY }

struct BasicNode {
    BasicNode* left;
    BasicNode* right;
    BasicNode* parent;
};

struct SplayNode : BasicNode {
    
}

struct RBNode : BasicNode {
    Color color;
};

struct AVLNode : BasicNode {
    unsigned int height;
};

....

???? node_;

if(condition == 1)
   node = new AVLNode;
else if(condition == 2)
   node = new RBNode;
else
   node = new SplayNode;


how to make struct type selection
i just started to learn c++ and dont know how to select struct type depending on class template param, when i construct class.

What is expected output? Also we need a [mcve]

"i just started to learn c++..." Good c++ book

What are you hoping to achieve by making RB trees and AVL trees the same class? This strikes me as an awful, awful idea.

What is the condition for being selected? That is, what is the relationship between the template parameter and the declared structures? How are you supposed to select on of the structures manually(on paper).? As of now, the question is unclear.

using Node = ????

@vansergh We don't know what you want to alias Node for. So there is no way to answer your question. That is, Node = ????  is not enough to answer your question.

alias will be used for return of methods and as param in method

You can use constexpr if. There are other ways too. But for that you'll need to clarify the question.

??WICH???TYPE?? node_;
if(condition == 1)
node = new AVLNode;
else if(condition == 2)
node = new RBNode;
else
node = new SplayNode;

@vansergh You can just write BasicNode* node; as it is the base of all three shown structures.

and i will be able to use AVLNode params? node.height?

@v You'll have to use node->height since it is a pointer now. Also I would recommend continue reading the books I linked as those will cover all this in one of their chapters.

auto node = new AVLNode;

@vansergh auto is not what you think it is. It is a placeholder type. The type for auto is deduced from the initializer. See the books as those books will help you clarify your question as you'll be able to see the problem with the given code more easily then.

BasicNode* node = new AVLNode;
node->height = 10; // 'struct BasicNode' has no member named 'height'

These trees have much less in common than you think. You will probably notice this if you implement them separately first.

All your nodes derive from BasicNode, so you could have BasicNode * node, and then assign node to new AVLNode, new RBNode etc. having said that, using raw pointers in bot recommended in modern C++. Use smart pointer instead.

std::unique_ptr?

or may be union?

or std::variant?

@vansergh Note that this is not a discussion forum. All details should go in your question. Also you can just write the previous three comments(unique_ptr, union etc) into a single comment. You're not clarifying your question but asking about random c++ constructs. That have nothing to with the question.

This design is fundamentally flawed. AVLNode::left is now a BasicNode*, but it should be a AVLNode*. You can't have mixed trees.

Ignoring all the guff around it and just answering the question you have of, what is the best way to have a variable that can contain multiple types.
When I am in this situation; if what you have as node is a local variable, I move the rest of the code into a template (sometimes lambda) function so I can pass the type I want. If your node was a member variable I'd make it a union or varient of the types it could be.  Here I would use a union as all the possible types are derived from the same base and it would be harder to access members of the base class if it was a varient.

    enum class Color { BLACK, RED };
    enum class TransplantMode { DEFAULT, LEFT, RIGHT };
    enum class TraverseMode { CONTINUOUS, RECURSIVE };
    enum class TreeModel { SPLAY, RED_BLACK, AVL };

....

    template <class DataType>
    class BaseNode {
    public:
        DataType data;
    };

    template <class DataType>
    class SplayNode : public BaseNode<DataType> {
    public:
        SplayNode<DataType>* left;
        SplayNode<DataType>* right;
        SplayNode<DataType>* parent;
    };

    template <class DataType>
    class AVLNode : public BaseNode<DataType> {
    public:
        AVLNode<DataType>* left;
        AVLNode<DataType>* right;
        AVLNode<DataType>* parent;
        unsigned int height;
    };

    template <class DataType>
    class RBNode: public BaseNode<DataType> {
    public:
        RBNode<DataType>* left;
        RBNode<DataType>* right;
        RBNode<DataType>* parent;
        unsigned int height;
    };

....

    template <class DataType, class NodeType, const TreeModel model>
    class BaseTree {

       ....

    }

    template <class DataType>
    class RBTree : private BaseTree<DataType, RBNode<DataType>, TreeModel::RED_BLACK> {

       ....
         
    };

    template <class DataType>
    class AVLTree : private BaseTree<DataType, AVLNode<DataType>, TreeModel::AVL> {

       ....
         
    };

    template <class DataType>
    class SplayTree : private BaseTree<DataType, SplayNode<DataType>, TreeModel::SPLAY> {

       ....
         
    };
    

